# Does let clause in parallel linq force the parallel evaluation?

Tags: .net, linq

On the xamarin iOS site there is the following parallel linq example.

```
from item in items.AsParallel ()
   let result = DoExpensiveWork (item)
   select result;
```

Could this not have been written

```
from item in items.AsParallel ()
   select DoExpensiveWork (item);
```

Or is there a reason for the let clause? Does this force it to be evaluated in parallel?

Comment: The output will be the same, and there is no difference in parallel execution of both queries either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the generated code (decompiled of course):

```
private static void WithLet(IEnumerable<int> items)
{
  ParallelEnumerable.Select(ParallelEnumerable.Select(ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel<int>(items), item =>
  {
    var local_0 = new
    {
      item = item,
      result = Program.DoExpensiveWork(item)
    };
    return local_0;
  }), param0 => param0.result);
}

private static void WithoutLet(IEnumerable<int> items)
{
  ParallelEnumerable.Select<int, object>(ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel<int>(items), (Func<int, object>) (item => Program.DoExpensiveWork(item)));
}
```

As we can see the only difference between the two methods is that an intermediate local variable is created.  The assignment to this local variable does not change the program's behaviour.

To answer your question more specifically the code that forces the execution to be in parallel is actually the call to `ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel`. LINQ queries are only executed when enumerated so it stands to reason that it is the generator of the `IEnumerable<>` that specifies whether it is executed in parallel or not.